# Outlook 2010 VSTO - Prevent form New Appointment from showing

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

Here's the current situation:

Whenever you create a new appointment in Outlook's calendar, the default form will show up which you can use to create the appointment.

Now it's possible to add an event-listener to whenever a new item has been created (ItemAddEventHandler). However, this happens **after** the default form was shown.

Is it possible to prevent the default form from showing up and instead show my own form?

I have already looked into Custom Form Regions, but that can't do the thing I want the way I want it.

Does someone have an idea where and how I can prevent this default form from showing and/or have information about it?

Thanks in advance